# How can i get the client's browser displayed address with Asp.NET?

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I 'm implementing my version of "ShareThis" in my webpage.

How can i get the client's browser displayed address with Asp.NET?

I am little confused with this one since the *url to share*...

1) is created with URL rewriting

2) contains Greek characters.

P.S. The client url is like `example.com/ελληνικα/βιβλια`

Comment: to clarify - are you saying when the browser has one url and the server sees it differently because of rewriting, how do you get the client URL? something like `somesite.com/products/computers/` in the browser vs the real/server url `somesite.com/products.aspx?cat=computers`?

Comment: Something like `example.com/ελληνικα/βιβλια`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command, its get what is on url (even if has pass url-rewriting)

```
Request.RawUrl
```

Of cource you can go and with javascript solution that mention here.

:) ευκολο.

**Update**
I first answer with RawUrl because of the asp.net tag, and not any javascript tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript to help you on this one :)

Have a Javascript function to extract the url of the browser through

```
location.href
```

Just try alert(location.href) if you have a javascript debugger in your browser, it works ;)

And then alter the href attribute of the anchor () tag of your choice )

```
    document.getElementById('facebooksubmit').href = "facebook.com/submiturl?url=" + location.href;
```

To make sure this runs,

```
<body onload="changeurlfunction();">
```